# Difference between Granger causality and VAR(1)?

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality

For my VAR(1) I get that the causal variable in each equation is statistically significant at 10%. But for Granger causality at 10% I only get that 1 variable granger causes the other and not the other way round. How is that possible?

**Edit:**

VAR:

```
   x = 2y + u 
   
   y = 3x + u
```

Granger Causality:

```
x g-causes y 
                               
y does not g-cause x
```

So, why does y not g-cause x?

Comment: Could you edit the post to include the output of your VAR model estimation and Granger 
causality test?

Comment: This is not a model that could be used for testing Granger causality. You need a full VAR model, and this is not it; own lags are missing. (I hope you are using lagged variables on the right hand side, but your equations do not indicate that.)

Comment: @RichardHardy its own lags were not significant at 10% therefore I didn't include them.

Comment: The point is not to exclude insignificant variables from the model but to have them in and to test for their significance. This is how the Granger causality test works.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't get it. Why would we test for significance of something that we know is not significant?

Comment: How would you know ahead of time what is significant if you have not tested for that?

Comment: @RichardHardy using the VAR results' significance of coefficients

Comment: If the coefficients are not in the model, there is no direct way to assess their significance. If you are assessing their significance, I presume they are in the model. If they are in the model (and I have suggested to include them), then you can assess the significance and at the same time test for Granger causality. In the simplest possible example, a bivariate VAR(1), you need to look at the coefficient on lag of $x$ in the equation for $y$ and lag of $y$ in the equation for $x$. Does that clarify that?

Answer (score 1):

If it is the same variable that is statistically significant at 10% in each equation, why are you surprised? For Granger causality of (1) $x\xrightarrow{Granger}y$ and (2) $y\xrightarrow{Granger}x$, you would look at different variables in different equations:

- For (1), you would look at lagged $x$ in the equation of $y$.
- For (2), you would look at lagged $y$ in the equation of $x$.

Comment: I edited my question to explain what I meant.